# Problemas con la instalacion de la Libreria BarcodeLib

Tags: c#

mi problema es el siguiente: estoy instalando la librería BarcodeLib para generar códigos de barras, pero me presenta el siguiente error:

Package 'BarcodeLib.2.2.5' does not exist in project 'UI'
Could not install package 'BarcodeLib 2.2.5'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
========== Finished ==========

Cambio el nombre de la carpeta como lo indicaron aquí: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42039069/could-not-install-package-you-are-trying-to-install-this-package-into-a-pr

Se instala correctamente, pero cuando intento llamar la librería, no aparece, dejo una foto, para que sea mas claro, espero que me entiendan y me ayuden.

Comment: Que version de net framework estas usando para desarrollar ? 
Eso de renombrar la carpeta no deberias hacerlo, si una libreria no soporta la version de framework que usas entonces o actualizas tu desarrollo para usar la version compatible o buscas otra libreria que si lo haga

Comment: Estoy usando la versión 4.5.2, cuando la cambió me da ese mismo error pero con la versión que cambié

Comment: cuantos proyectos tienes en el solucion? y en cual estas agregando desde nuget la libreria barcode?

Comment: Tengo 3 Proyectos, 2 del tipo Libreria de clase y un Win Form, lo estoy agregando desde el Wind Forms